# How to disable a <md-select> in <md-field> on VueJS Material

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

`<md-select>` is shown when I click `<md-field>` component.

And `<md-select>` component is turn off when I click outside area of `<md-field>`.

I want to turn off `<md-select>` component when I click some button.

How can I add custom event for turn off `<md-select>` component?

This is a document link for `select` component.
[Vue Material - Select](https://www.creative-tim.com/vuematerial/components/select)

And this is a template.

```js
<md-field>
  <label for="movie">Movie</label>
  <md-select v-model="movie" name="movie" id="movie">
    <md-option value="fight-club">Fight Club</md-option>
    <md-option value="godfather">Godfather</md-option>
    <md-option value="godfather-ii">Godfather II</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button and add click event

```
<button @click="disableButtonClicked">Click to disable</button>
```

Then you can change your component's variable let's call it isDisabled

```
<md-field>
  <label for="movie">Movie</label>
  <md-select v-model="movie" name="movie" id="movie"  :disabled="isDisabled" ref="mdSelect">
    <md-option value="fight-club">Fight Club</md-option>
    <md-option value="godfather">Godfather</md-option>
    <md-option value="godfather-ii">Godfather II</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-field>
```

or you can use its ref like

```
this.$refs.mdSelect
```

and then do which action you want.

Comment: sorry, my fault.
What I meant was `turn off`, not disable. I edited my question.

Comment: I do not have the package so can you please check if there is a event for close or something like that?